# Uploading a file on drive using python (Exponential backoff for HttpError 500)

Tags: python, google-oauth, http-error, httplib2

**A python code that uploads on google drive ...**

**Link:** http://wescpy.blogspot.in/2015/12/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import os

from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags) \
            if flags else tools.run(flow, store)
DRIVE = build('drive', 'v2', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

FILES = (   
    ('ex.xls', False),
    ('ex.xls', True),
)

for filename, convert in FILES:
    metadata = {'title': filename}
    res = DRIVE.files().insert(convert=convert, body=metadata,
            media_body=filename, fields='mimeType,exportLinks').execute()

    if res:
        print('Uploaded1: "%s" (%s)' % (filename, res['mimeType']))

if res:
    MIMETYPE = 'application/pdf'
    res, data = DRIVE._http.request(res['exportLinks'][MIMETYPE])
    if data:
        fn = '%s.pdf' % os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        with open(fn, 'wb') as fh:
            fh.write(data)
        print('Downloaded "%s" (%s)' % (fn, MIMETYPE))
```

**Error:**

```
Uploaded1: "ex.xls" (application/vnd.ms-excel)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wescpy.py", line 32, in <module>
    media_body=filename, fields='mimeType,exportLinks').execute()
  File "/home/optimus/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/optimus/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 842, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 500 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?convert=true&fields=mimeType%2CexportLinks&alt=json&uploadType=multipart returned "">
```

**Documentation** (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/handle-errors)

Suggested: Use exponential backoff, include a check before retrying non-idempotent requests.

1. How to solve these errors or should I use backoff 1.3.1 in python ?
2. And what is `store = file.Storage('storage.json')`

Comment: What is the error exactly?  Thats just a stack trace.

Comment: googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: **HttpError 500**

Comment: what happens if you try to send the same request again?

Comment: Same error ... Although it's uploading two files: One as it is and other opens up in spreadsheet